# installing virtual Centos 6 iso on mac air

Tags: macos, centos, virtualbox, iso

i am tring to install VM from centos[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bebn2.png) iso file , my pc is mac air , 
the installation failed with this error :

i need help to pass this message , and why i am getting it ,

thanks

Comment: It kind of looks like your disk is maybe too small, so it might be an idea to indicate how big you made it. This is not a programming question though, so I am voting to close it. Try one of the other, more appropriate SE sites.

Comment: my storage is quite enough to install virtual Centos , 200GB , its related to virtualbox and install virtual machine , i saw alot of quetions o stackoverflow related to that topic

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You'll also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

i found solution for my question , so i want share it for who face the same issue , 
just re-install the virtual machine and change the storage size to be more bigger , for my installation i changed to be 100G , it was 20G and looks not enough for installing Centos ,

thanks